# IIS 7 cannot display http://localhost

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008

I am having a torrid time trying to figure out why I cannot display http://localhost in the web browser.

I keep getting the 404 not found error. I tried looking in the `wwwroot folder` and added the http://localhost/iisstart.html still nothing happened.

There is a web service and a web application added to the default web site and I am not sure if this has something to do with this but all this worked fine previously.

Comment: There are loads of reasons why this might not be working. Are all the IIS services enabled? Has ASP.NET been registered with IIS? Has it ever worked alongside your web service?

Comment: it has worked with the webservice which is not mine...the only IIS service not enabled is asp.net state service...ASP.NET has been registered within the application pools.